# Transaction Complete Err when calling async function within async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, knex.js

I have the following async function to duplicate a record within a postgres database table called 'Questionnaires':

```js
const duplicateQuestionnaire = async(trx, originalQuestionnaireId) => {
  const originalQuestionnaire = await trx
    .select("*")
    .from("Questionnaires")
    .where({
      id: originalQuestionnaireId
    })
    .then(head);

  const newQuestionnaireId = await trx
    .table("Questionnaires")
    .insert(omit(originalQuestionnaire, "id"))
    .returning("id")
    .then(head);

  const sectionIDs = await trx
    .select("id")
    .from("Sections")
    .where({
      QuestionnaireId: originalQuestionnaireId
    });

  sectionIDs.map(element => {
    duplicateSection(trx, element.id, newQuestionnaireId);
  });

  return trx
    .select("*")
    .from("Questionnaires")
    .where({
      id: newQuestionnaireId
    })
    .then(head);
};
```

After duplicating, it will call a second async function to duplicate a record within a table called 'Sections':

```js
const duplicateSection = async (trx, sectionId, newQuestionnaireId) => {
  const originalSection = await trx
    .select("*")
    .from("Sections")
    .where({ id: sectionId })
    .then(head);

  const newSection = omit(originalSection, "id");

  newQuestionnaireId ? (newSection.QuestionnaireId = newQuestionnaireId) : null;

  const newSectionId = await trx
    .table("Sections")
    .insert(newSection)
    .returning("id")
    .then(head);

  return trx
    .select("*")
    .from("Sections")
    .where({ id: newSectionId })
    .then(head);
};
```

> These functions are designed with a hierarchy in mind: `duplicateQuestionnaire` calls `duplicateSection` as a questionnaire contains sections. The latter function can be called without calling the former initially and does not call it as part of its actions.
>
> The return value of each function is used as a GraphQL return.

These functions both have the desired effect on the database; they work. However, `duplicateQuestionnaire` is flagging this error:

```js
(node:172) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Transaction query already complete, run with DEBUG=knex:tx for more info
web_1  |     at completedError (/app/node_modules/knex/lib/transaction.js:303:9)
web_1  |     at /app/node_modules/knex/lib/transaction.js:277:22
web_1  | From previous event:
web_1  |     at Client_PG.trxClient.query (/app/node_modules/knex/lib/transaction.js:275:34)
web_1  |     at Runner.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/knex/lib/runner.js:155:36)
web_1  | From previous event:
web_1  |     at /app/node_modules/knex/lib/runner.js:61:21
web_1  |     at runCallback (timers.js:810:20)
web_1  |     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:768:5)
web_1  |     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:745:5)
web_1  | From previous event:
web_1  |     at Runner.run (/app/node_modules/knex/lib/runner.js:47:31)
web_1  |     at Builder.Target.then (/app/node_modules/knex/lib/interface.js:39:43)
web_1  |     at duplicateSection (/app/repositories/DuplicateRepository.js:49:6)
web_1  |     at <anonymous>
web_1  | (node:172) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
web_1  | (node:172) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I know the issue is around how I'm handling each `duplicateSection` call within the `.map()` but, after some research and intense googling, I'm still struggling to resolve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to `await` all promises returned by duplicateSections:

```
 await Promise.all(sectionIDs.map(element =>
    duplicateSection(trx, element.id, newQuestionnaireId)
 ));
```

That not only ensures that all sections get copied before you run the final query, it also chains rejected promises.

Comment: Cheers! Fyi, you're missing a closing bracket on the final line. Otherwise, works like a dream.

Comment: @matt glad to help :)